# INNER JOIN : where clause is too ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error `"Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'restaurant_id' in where clause is ambiguous' in"`.

a) How do I use bindparam on JOIN? Is that even the problem causing this error?

```
function restaurant(PDO $dbh, $username) {
   global $dbh;
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
      SELECT        *
      FROM          users u
      INNER JOIN    menues m
      ON            u.user_id = m.restaurant_id
      INNER JOIN    users_slider s
      ON            m.restaurant_id = s.restaurant_id
      WHERE         restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
   ");

   $stmt->bindParam(":restaurant_id", $_GET['r']);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally joining `resturant_id` and `user_id` because they dont sound like they shoudl have a key relationship

Comment: Ok cool, just checking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```sql
...
WHERE     restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
```

to

```sql
...
WHERE     m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
          ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use `m.restaurant_id`or`s.restaurant_id` in where condition according to your table  it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Always use alias for avoiding conflict in join query . Here `restaurant_id` should be `m.restaurant_id`.

Try this query :-

```
SELECT        *
      FROM          users u
      INNER JOIN    menues m
      ON            u.user_id = m.restaurant_id
      INNER JOIN    users_slider s
      ON            m.restaurant_id = s.restaurant_id
      WHERE         m.restaurant_id =:restaurant_id
```

Answer (score 1):

put where condition like WHERE m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id

```
function restaurant(PDO $dbh, $username) {
   global $dbh;
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
      SELECT        *
      FROM      users u
      INNER JOIN    menues m
      ON            u.user_id = m.restaurant_id
      INNER JOIN    users_slider s
      ON            m.restaurant_id = s.restaurant_id
      WHERE     m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
   ");

   $stmt->bindParam(":restaurant_id", $_GET['r']);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```